# In Embedded Octave C++ how do I execute a script file? ("error: invalid call to script")

Tags: c++, octave

I am writing a c++ oct-file that I would like to use as a link between my c++ code and scripts that were written in Octave. I can build and execute with no problems, and as long as I am doing simple things, it seems to work. I can even call functions in a script file with `feval()`! I just can't seem to figure out how to execute an entire script file..

If I try this simple program, I get an error, but I'm not sure why

```
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/toplev.h> // for do_octave_atexit

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void runscript(const string &file) {

    cout << "attempting to run: " << file << endl;

    int parse_status = 0;
    eval_string(file, false, parse_status);
    cout << "parse_status: " << parse_status << endl;

    eval_string(file, false, parse_status, 0); // I'm not sure what the difference here is or 
                                  // what the value 0 means, I can't find any documentation on 
                                  // what `hargout` is.. See Note {1} below
    cout << "parse_status: " << parse_status << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Set-up
    char *oct_argv[3] = {(char*)"embedded", (char*)"-q", (char*)"--interactive"};
    octave_main(3, oct_argv, true);


    // Attempt to run script    
    runscript("Script1");
    runscript("Script1.m");


    // `a` should be defined after running Script1.m..
    octave_value_list a = get_top_level_value("a", false);

    do_octave_atexit ();

    return 0;
}
```

Script1.m is very simple and looks like this:

```
a = 1000;
a
```

When I run, I always get this output:

```
attempting to run: Script1
error: invalid call to script /Users/Daly/Documents/School/EECS/Labs/GitHub/deep/Octave/    Script1.m
parse_status: 0
parse_status: 0
attempting to run: Script1.m
parse_status: 0
parse_status: 0
error: get_top_level_value: undefined symbol 'a'
```

It only ever complains about the invalid call the first time, no matter how many times I try to eval_string or in what order.

Notes: {1} After searching for `error: invalid call to script`, I found [this source code](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/de/d5e/ov-usr-fcn_8cc_source.html) which at line 00155 raises this exact error if `nargout` isn't 0, so I thought they might be related?

But anyway, maybe this isn't the right way to be going about it. What is the correct way to execute an entire octave script from an octave-embedded c++ program? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use [`source_file()`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d4/d2b/parse_8h.html#a1208e1267904bf5ee6b0653aeb8f5705) instead of `eval_string()`. Anyway, I would recommend asking this in the [Octave help mailing list](https://mailman.cae.wisc.edu/listinfo/help-octave) or looking into the source of `parse.h` or `oct-parse.cc` (this file will be generated during the build process) which implements the octave function source.

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right. `source_file()` is what I was looking for, thank you. Okay, yeah great I will. It's tough without comments trying to figure out some of the functions in the header files. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the function [`source_file()`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d4/d2b/parse_8h.html#a1208e1267904bf5ee6b0653aeb8f5705) rather than `eval_string()`. Take a look into the `parser.h` file which unfortunately doesn't have a lot of comments. The names are quite self-explanatory so you shouldn't have a lot of problems.

Also, you're pretty much trying to reimplement Octave's `source` function. If you really want to implement it again, look into the oct-parse.cc file (generated during the build process with flex and bison).